# Attach Debug with Lerna and nest.js

Tags: debugging, nestjs, vscode-debugger, lerna, vscode-tasks

Scenario:

- I have created a lerna project with `lerna init`
- I have added a new package for backend application with nest.js
- added a dev script to the monorepo package.json so that will run the nest app, which it does

I don't want to run `npm run dev` manually each time, rather I want to use the debugger to launch the script and attach it to it automatically (this is what I do in my workplace, so I'm trying to reproduce the architecture myself)

- made an attach configuration in my launch.json file

```
{
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach by Process ID",
            "processId": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "port": 9229,
            "preLaunchTask": "npm: dev"
        }
```

- and created the prelaunch script in task.json as follow

```
{
            "type": "npm",
            "script": "dev",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "label": "npm: dev",
            "detail": "lerna run dev"
        }
```

now, I can't seems to find any proper documentation about it, but here's what happens:

- running the debugger runs the script and the nest application starts
- the debugger is not attached
- the debugger gets attached only when I kill the running task pressing ctrl+c (which is the nest application running)

Can someone help me out? what am I doing wrong?